# NSThread running a class

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

Every the example I find on the internet (including Apple doc) sets the target to self like this :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadedTask) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Since i would like to do a more complex task in background (involving multiple methods), I thought of creating a class `Task` called like this :

```
Task *task = [[Task alloc] init];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:task withObject:nil];
```

but I wonder, how will be handled the instance variables of my class `Task` ? in my method `main` can I safely call methods of my class `Task` using `[self myMethod]` and modifying members variables assuming I'm the only thread accessing it ?

This way of handling threads seems weird to me, sorry if my question is stupid ^^

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one `NSThread` (including the main thread) for each `Task` then yes, you can do whatever you want. As soon as more than one thread can be accessing certain data simultaniously, you'll have to provide synchronization.

Comment: thanks ! So i'll try that immediately, then i'll accept you answer (since stackoverflow force me to wait to accept anyway ^^)